# Linux-OS missing after installing in Virtualbox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, macos-sierra, parrot-os

I installed Parrot Security os-4.8 twice on virtualbox on my MacBook Air (2015), and after successful installation with no errors (both times), after rebooting virtualbox, again I get the option to use it as live or install with other options that appears as if the OS is not installed.
I checked the vdi and it appears to be of 6gb in size(I think the OS is still there).

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.(sorry for bad English)

Comment: Not a programming question. Probably more suitable for the Superuser community.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you did not download the Virtual Image File ( OVA File)

( Your English is great BTW )

go to -  https://parrotlinux.org/download/

Next -Go to the Virtual Tab
[image: Go to the Virtual Tab]

Download This Image

[image: Download This Image]

Click on the OVA file after download to import into Virtual Box

IMPORTANT NOTE - the default password and super user password  for this machines image is - toor